# TYPO3 | Extbase / Fluid - How can I fill <f:form.select.optgroup> from a domain object / database?

Tags: forms, typo3, fluid, extbase, optgroup

Hi I'm struggling with the <f:form.select>
I need to populate the values with option groups but according to the manual all I can find is how to manually create optgroup's.

Does anybody know a way to fill the select with values from the object / database?

This select works fine but doesn't create option groups obviously
<f:form.select options="{positionen}"  optionLabelField="title" multiple="1"  id="position" property="position" size="10" class="form-control  select2-hs" />

Now how could I modify the view so that it'll be like this:

```
<select class="form-control select2-multiple select2-multiple-max3" name="position[]">
<optgroup label="Geschäftsführung / Management">
 <option value="1">Geschäftsführer KMU (Bereich Handel / Dienstleistung)</option>
<option value="2">Geschäftsführer Großunternehmen (Bereich Handel / Dienstleistung)</option>
<option value="3">Geschäftsführer KMU (Bereich Produktion)</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Steuern / Revision / Treuhand">
...
```

The content of the object {positionen} looks like this:
[(Screenshot of fluid debug output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtXI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need your own logic for grouping, either by preparing groups in your controller or using `<f:groupedFor>`:

```html
<f:select property="position">
  <f:groupedFor
    each="{positions}"
    as="areaPositions"
    groupBy="area"
    groupKey="area"
  >

    <f:form.select.optgroup label="{area.title}">

      <f:for each="{areaPositions}" as="position">

        <f:form.select.option value="{position.uid}">
          {position.title}
        </f:form.select.option>

      </f:for>

    </f:form.select.optgroup>

  </f:groupedFor>
</f:select>
```

Here it is assumed that you have loaded all possible `positions` (e.g. from a `PositionRepository`) and passed it to the template. Each position should have a related `area` (1:1) and each area should have a `title`. This way you can group positions by their `area` and use the area `title` as option group label.

Afterwards all positions for each area are rendered as select options assuming that each position has a `title`.